# Cloud Functions cant not get token from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

im trying to send message from function but its always got "Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array" 
but here is where my token stored:

- path

  -- UID

  +++-- token

---

and here my code

```
    exports.mess = functions.database.ref('/path/{uid}')
        .onWrite(event => {
        var ref = admin.database().ref(`token`);
        return ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
       const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'You have been invited to a trip.',
                body: 'Tap here to check it out!'
            }
       };

       admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)

      },function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });

       });
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `snapshot.val()`? Try logging it. The error message suggests it's not what you think.

It looks like you're querying the wrong location in your database.  Your question says your token is stored under the UID, but your query doesn't consider a UID at all.

Comment: log of snapshot.val() return null as u said , but admin.database().ref(`token`) isnt collect from /path/{uid} at the top?

Comment: No, it's not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to use the value of the `token` property of the user who triggered the Cloud Function. In that case you don't need to attach a separate listener, as the value is already available inside the `context` parameter.

```
exports.mess = functions.database.ref('/path/{uid}')
.onWrite(event => {
    let token = event.after.child('token').val()
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'You have been invited to a trip.',
            body: 'Tap here to check it out!'
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)
});
```