# cloud functions-firestore: how to get tokens from 2 queries

Tags: promise, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

I want to send notifications to 2 different types of users when a `client` document is created. First, I have to search `providers` collection for nearby providers who want nearby clients, and for remote providers who don't care about distance so that I can send notifications to all of them. I tried to implement these 2 queries, and send notifications, but failed. The error message was `Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array`. What is wrong with this following code?

```
exports.clientRegisterNotification = functions.firestore
.document("crews/{crew}/clients/{client}")
.onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
  try {
    const clientGeopoint = snapshot.data().g.geopoint;
    const clientField = snapshot.data().field;

    const nearCollection = geofirestore.collectionGroup("providers");
    const remoteCollection = firestore.collectionGroup("providers");
    
    const query1 = remoteCollection.where("wantNear", "==", 'false')
        .where("field", "==", clientField);
    const query2 = nearCollection.near({center: clientGeopoint, radius: 10}).where("wantNear", "==", 'true')
        .where("field", "==", clientField);
    
    const tokenArray = [];

    const [remotePro, nearPro] = await Promise.all([query1.get(), query2.get()]);

    remotePro.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const token1 = doc.data().fcmToken;
        tokenArray.push(token1);

    nearPro.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const token2 = doc.data().fcmToken;
        tokenArray.push(token2);
      });
    const message = {
      "notification": {
        title: ...,
        body: ...,
      },
     };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenArray, message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please review this thread if it answers your question: [Error with registration token in FCM with Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996034/cloud-functions-cant-not-get-token-from-realtime-database?rq=1).
Can you also provide the JSON with your `registration-tokens`?

Comment: @FaridShumbar Thanks Farid. I have each user's fcmToken saved in firestore. So if fcmToken equals to registration tokens, I provided the JSON with my registration-tokens. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I edited my code part above using another Promise method for collecting all the tokens from the query. Please check if anything is wrong.

Comment: It looks like the error that points to an empty array or string occurs because the `clientField` variable is not populated